# How is the Radius of Convergence of a Series determined?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, ratio

Consider $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{(n+1)^2}$$ which by the ratio test the ratio of two consecutive terms converges to $|x|$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and has a radius of convergence equal to $1$.

Now consider $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(2^n+n^2)x^n$$ which by the ratio test the ratio of two consecutive terms converges to $2|x|$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and has a radius of convergence equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.

My question is why the radius of convergence takes these values ($1$ for the former and $\frac{1}{2}$ for the latter)?

You have my sympathy if this is blatantly obvious to you, but it is not clear to me. So could someone please explain in simple English why the radius of convergence takes those values above?

Or, put in another way, from the second summation you *know* by the ratio test that the ratio of two of its consecutive terms converges to $2|x|$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ how then do you proceed to determine the radius of convergence?

Many thanks.

Comment: The first sum you wrote does not converge to $|x|$. The second does not converge to $2|x|$.

Comment: @5xum: I think BLAZE means that the ratio of two adjacent terms of the series converges to $|x|$ and $2|x|$, respectively, and thus for $|x| \le 1$ and $|x| \le 2$, respectively, the series converges by the ratio test.

Comment: @Tintarn yes that is precisely what I meant apologies for any ambiguity

Comment: @BLAZE Then correct what you wrote. Also, I don't really unerstand the question then. You know how to calculate the radius of convergence, so now asking "why is the radius such as it is" is really unclear. It's like asking why the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$

Comment: @5xum No I don't understand how to calculate the radius of convergence else I would not be asking. These results were given without proof.

Comment: One way to do this job is  Cauchy-Hadamard theorem, or essentially, Cauchy root test. (Of course, you may also do it based on d'Alembert root test. )

Comment: @Vim still confused sorry.

Comment: @BLAZE It is not convenient for me to browse Wikipedia now so I'm currently unable to give you a link in my comment, but you yourself can search for, say, *Cauchy-Hadamard theorem* on Wikipedia, that might be helpful.

Comment: @BLAZE look up these theorems. they give you formula to compute the radius of convergence.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Finding_the_radius_of_convergence

Comment: @BLAZE d'Alembert *ratio* test, not *root*, sorry for that typo (5min have passed I can't make an edit for correction).

Comment: Do you know why the ratio test is what it is, or why it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for the [Radius of Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) of
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n
$$
is
$$
R=\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|a_n\right|^{1/n}\right)^{-1}
$$
This formula is derived using the [Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).

It is pretty easy to apply this to the series in the question.

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{(n+1)^2}\right)^{1/n}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)^{-2/n}\\
&=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}\right)^{-2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-2/n}\\[9pt]
&=1^{-2}\cdot1^0\\[12pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$
giving a radius of convergence of $1$.

Likewise,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2^n+n^2\right)^{1/n}
&=2\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{n^2}{2^n}\right)^{1/n}\\
&=2\cdot1^0\\[6pt]
&=2
\end{align}
$$
giving a radius of convergence of $\frac12$.

---

As you say, in the second series, the ratio of the absolute values of the terms tends to $2|x|$. For the series to converge, the ratio needs to be $\le1$. Thus, we need $|x|\le\frac12$. Therefore, the radius of convergence is $\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting aspect is to evaluate the series of the question. 
Consider
\begin{align}
S_{1}(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, x^{n}}{(n+1)^{2}} \\
S_{2}(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \, (2^{n} + n^{2}) \, x^{n}.
\end{align}
The first series:
\begin{align}
\partial_{x} \left(x \, S_{1}(x) \right) &= \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, x^{n}}{n+1} = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \, x^{n-1}}{n} = \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}.
\end{align}
or
$$S_{1}(x) = - \frac{1}{x} \, Li_{2}(-x),$$
where $Li_{2}(x)$ is the dilogarithm function. The second series follows from
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^{2} \, x^{n} = \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^{3}}$$
and is seen to be
$$S_{2}(x) = \frac{1}{1+2x} - \frac{x(1-x)}{(1+x)^{3}}.$$