# How to find Radius of Convergence in general?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am now learning complex analysis and my very first obstacle is that I cannot find a systematic way to tackle the problem of finding radius of convergence. In particular, I am not familiar with $\lim \sup$.

The only thing I use is the Cauchy-Hadamard formula:

> Consider $\sum c_n z^n$. The radius of convergence of this series, R,
>   is given by $$ R = \left( \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} | c_n |
>  ^{\frac{1}{n}} \right)^{-1} .$$

The following are some questions I have encountered. I mention them so as to show my logic to solve these problems. I hope that you can give me some instructions.

For example, I want to find the radius of convergence of $\sum z^{n!}$. I checked in MSE, and found the solution using ratio test.

Then I came across the problem of finding R of $\sum (n+2^n)z^n$. And now I am stuck when using Cauchy Hadamard formula. Then I come up with this solution:

> Note that $$\sum (n+2^n)z^n = \sum nz^n + \sum (2z)^n.$$ The first sum
>   will converge for $|z|<1$ and the second sum would converge for
>   $|2z|<1$, i.e. $|z|<0.5$. Hence, $R= 0.5$.
>   Is there any problem?

I also have the following problem:

> Suppose $\sum c_n z^n$ has a radius of convergence R. Find the radius
>   of convergence of $\sum n^p c_n z^n$.

Again, I make use of the Cauchy Hadamard formula $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} | n^pc_n | ^{\frac{1}{n}}$. But I don't know what can be done for that.

**I appreciate that you can give me some ideas on the questions. But more importantly, it would be of my best interest that you can introduce more on finding radius of convergence.**

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408978/how-is-the-radius-of-convergence-of-a-series-determined) might help.

Comment: @BLAZE : thats more or less the same as my problem! turns out i am not the only one who gets stuck here :P

Comment: I glad I'm not the only one either :)

Answer (score 1):

It is true in general that the radius of convergence for a power series expansion of a function is the distance from the center to the nearest singularity.

That can be very useful if you know what the function is in closed form.

**Addendum:** The "center" is the $z_0$ that is used in the powers $(z-z_0)^n$. In the case that your summands are of the form $c_nz^n$, the center is $0$ since $z^n\equiv (z-0)^n$.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In fact, I have just learnt complex analysis for a few weeks and we have not cover the singularity yet. Do we have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You know that

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} |c_n|^{1/n} = \frac1{R}$$

Then

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} |n^p c_n|^{1/n} =\left (\limsup_{n \to \infty} n^{p/n}  \right )  \left (\limsup_{n \to \infty} |c_n|^{1/n}  \right )$$

because each limit exists.  Note that

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} n^{p/n} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} e^{p \log{n}/n} $$

Note that

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log{n}}{n} = 0$$

so that

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} n^{p/n} = 1$$

Thus, the radius of convergence is $R$.